# Postgresql 9.2.2. There is an entry for table "xxx", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: php, postgresql

I recieve an error when I try to execute the next query in Postgresql 9.2.2.

```
SELECT emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, t.ttl as total, COALESCE(t.imported,0), COALESCE(t.spend, 0), COALESCE(t.available, 0), emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month
    FROM (
        SELECT employer_id,
            CAST (date_part('month', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as month,
            CAST (date_part('year', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as year
        FROM z_employer_wallet
        WHERE state = 1
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3) as emp_wallet_periods
    INNER JOIN get_employers_availability_by_month(emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month) as t ON t.employerId = emp_wallet_periods.employer_id
    ORDER BY emp_wallet_periods.year DESC, t.available DESC, emp_wallet_periods.month DESC
```

The same query works perfect in Postgresql 9.5.6.

The exact error message which I receive is:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table
> "emp_wallet_periods" LINE 9:  INNER JOIN
> get_employers_availability_by_month(emp_wallet_p...
>
> ^ HINT:  There is an entry for table "emp_wallet_periods", but it cannot be
> referenced from this part of the query.

What I miss?

Comment: Thank you Lelio Faieta for the editing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this syntax is not available in Postgres 9.2. LATERAL option for FROM-clause subqueries and function calls was introduced in [Postgres 9.3.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-3.html)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 ON boolean_expression`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-table-expressions.html

As you can see, you cannot use function in your JOIN

```
...get_employers_availability_by_month(emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month) as t...
```

What you can do is `SELECT get_employers_availability_by_month(emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month) FROM original_query`

And join results.

Comment: Hi Alexey Soshin. Can you give some related example. Honestly I'm new in Postgresql and I don't understand you very well. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response Alexey. I would test your suggestion and will come back to share results.

Comment: Fellow @arturios already wrote what I meant, please check his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, t.ttl as total, COALESCE(t.imported,0), COALESCE(t.spend, 0), COALESCE(t.available, 0), emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month
    FROM (
        SELECT employer_id,
            CAST (date_part('month', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as month,
            CAST (date_part('year', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as year
        FROM z_employer_wallet
        WHERE state = 1
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3) as emp_wallet_periods
    INNER JOIN (SELECT get_employers_availability_by_month(emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, emp_wallet_periods.year, emp_wallet_periods.month)
                FROM (SELECT employer_id,
                            CAST (date_part('month', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as month,
                            CAST (date_part('year', to_timestamp(date_created)) AS INTEGER) as year
                        FROM z_employer_wallet
                        WHERE state = 1
                        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3) as emp_wallet_periods) as t 
    ON t.employerId = emp_wallet_periods.employer_id
    ORDER BY emp_wallet_periods.year DESC, t.available DESC, emp_wallet_periods.month DESC
```

Comment: Nah. Not in 9.2.

Comment: Thank you very much @arturios for your response. I will test your suggestion and will come back to share results.

Comment: Hi @arturios. I tested your suggestion but does not work. I tried to rewrite some parts of the query but still not working. The main issue which I receive is that t.employer_id does not exists because the INNER JOIN retrieve kind of array as results.

Comment: I think you need to see what your function is returning, your function should return a table for this to work.

Comment: I will paste my function as Answer. The function returns Table.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't have any errors in the function. It works perfect on Postgresql 9.2.2 and 9.5.6. 

SELECT * FROM get_employers_availability_by_month(112181, 2018, 6);

If I pass parameters dynamicaly like my main Query in the post. Than I receive the error message. Which is pasted in the main Post.

Comment: @StefanChonov i mean with my answer the error is the same?

Comment: @arturios I'm sorry for my stupidis. The error which I receive when I execute your suggestion is:

ERROR:  column t.employer_id does not exist
LINE 15:     ON t.employer_id = emp_wallet_periods.employer_id
                ^

Comment: According to the query i submitted the column name should be "t.employerId", ON t.employerId = emp_wallet_periods.employer_id, did you change it?

Comment: @arturios. Yes actualy I changed. With the t.employerId the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is my full original function get_employers_availability_by_month();

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_employers_availability_by_month(eid integer, y integer, m integer)
RETURNS TABLE(employerId integer, ttl real, imported real, spend real, available real, year integer, month integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT emp_wallet.employer_id, SUM(emp_wallet.total) as total, emp_wallet_imported.imported, emp_wallet_spend.spend, CASE WHEN (emp_wallet_spend.spend > 0 AND emp_wallet_imported.imported is null) THEN CAST((0 - emp_wallet_spend.spend) as real)
        WHEN emp_wallet_spend.spend > 0 THEN (emp_wallet_imported.imported-emp_wallet_spend.spend)
        ELSE emp_wallet_imported.imported END AS availability, CAST(date_part('year', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created)) as INTEGER) as year, CAST(date_part('month', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created)) as INTEGER) as month
    FROM z_employer_wallet as emp_wallet
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT employer_id, SUM(total) AS imported
            FROM z_employer_wallet as emp_wal
            WHERE emp_wal.total > 0
                AND emp_wal.flow = 1
                AND emp_wal.state = 1
                AND emp_wal.employer_id = eid
                AND date_part('year', to_timestamp(emp_wal.date_created)) = y
                AND date_part('month', to_timestamp(emp_wal.date_created)) = m
            GROUP BY employer_id
        ) as emp_wallet_imported ON emp_wallet_imported.employer_id = emp_wallet.employer_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT employer_id, SUM(total) AS spend
            FROM z_employer_wallet as emp_wal
            WHERE emp_wal.total > 0
                AND emp_wal.flow = 2
                AND emp_wal.state = 1
                AND emp_wal.employer_id = eid
                AND date_part('month', to_timestamp(emp_wal.date_created)) = m
                AND date_part('year', to_timestamp(emp_wal.date_created)) = y
            GROUP BY employer_id
    ) as emp_wallet_spend ON emp_wallet_spend.employer_id = emp_wallet.employer_id
    WHERE emp_wallet.employer_id = eid
        AND date_part('month', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created)) = m
        AND date_part('year', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created)) = y
    GROUP BY emp_wallet.employer_id, emp_wallet_imported.imported, emp_wallet_spend.spend, date_part('month', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created)), date_part('year', to_timestamp(emp_wallet.date_created))
    ORDER BY emp_wallet.employer_id DESC;
RETURN;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I didn't find solution of my issue. Thank you very much for the help people. I'll rewrite the query. Have a nice day.